# How to convert HashMap<String, JSONObject> object into JSONArray

Tags: android, arrays, hashmap

I have HashMap with jsonobject I want to store all those values into JSONArray.

Is it possible ?

Please help me.

Comment: Unclear question. A Map and an Array are two fundamentally different data types. *How* should the mapping occur? (Hint: first convert the [Hash]Map into the appropriate List - at least conceptually - and then to a JSONArray.)

Comment: Could you please provide example ? which is helpful for me.

Comment: "*How* should the mapping occur?" - not without that being answered.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two json objects stored in hashmap :

```
HashMap<String, JSONOnject> stringJson = new HashMap<String, JSONObject>();
stringJson.put("key", jsonobject1);
stringJson.put("key1", jsonobject2); //remember the hashmap structure, its key value structure.
```

You can access this jsonObject by get method of hashmap:

```
JSONArray jarray = stringjson.get("key").getJsonArray("json array name"); //stringjson.get("key") will return jsonObject you stored.
```

But you can do this directly without saving json object to hashmap.